# Laravel eloquent relationship query does not work

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I would like to get all quizzes with the topics which have a `course_id`:

The `Topic` model has the following function:

```
public function quizzes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Quiz');
}
```

The Quizzes model has the following function:

```
public function topic()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Topic', 'topic_id');
}
```

This is the code in my controller function:

```
$topics = Topic::with('quizzes')->whereCourseId($course_id)->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();

return dd($topics->quizzes);
```

I get the following `Exception` error:

```
Property [quizzes] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

I seem not to know whats happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you want to get `quizzes` of collection not of one Model so loop over this collection like this :

```
foreach ($topics as $topic) {
    $topics->quizzes;  // <- this is fine :)
}
```

for debugging purpose you can do it like this :

```
dd($topics->fist()->quizzes);
```

---

For the second need you can do it like this :

```
$quizzes = Quizzes::whereHas('topic', function ($query) use ($course_id) {
        $query->where('course_id', $course_id);
    })->get();
```

Comment: Is there a way of getting the topics without the loop? I would want to get the list of quizzes at once?

Comment: That is not what you asked for :p You want list of all quizzes that have a topic with a course id is that true ?

Comment: Yes thats what I would want. Got any ideas?